# How come my counter is only returning 1?

Tags: python

How come my counter is only returning 1? I would like it to return the value of all the numbers, what am I doing wrong?

```
def custom_len(input):
    counter = 0
    for i in a:
        counter += 1
        return counter 

arr_input = input("enter arr :")
length = custom_len(arr_input)

print("length is ", length)
```

Comment: You're `return`ing inside the loop. A function *stops* when it `return`s.

Comment: oh man, can't believe I didn't catch that. shoot I'm rusty

Comment: That code would produce a `NameError` because `a` is never defined. Pease make sure that code you post actually demonstrates the error you are asking about.

Comment: @Billa That only applies to *assigning* to a name; you can't iterate over an undefined name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

move `return` outside for loop, loop is ending in first iteration due to `return` statement as because of which counter is 1.

```
def custom_len(input):
    counter = 0
    for i in input:
        counter += 1
    return counter 

arr_input = input("enter arr :")
length = custom_len(arr_input)

print("length is ", length)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you `return` the from a function the function terminates. And as your `return` inside the loop it return with first value of the loop and terminates. Your code should look as follows:

```
def custom_len(input):
  counter = 0
  for i in input:
    counter += 1
  return counter 
'''
here the program return a value and terminates.
i.e it won't execute following three lines. 
If you want to continue execution, you should move the above line of code to end of the program.
'''

arr_input = input("enter arr :")
length = custom_len(arr_input)

print("length is ", length)
```